# default value for DropDownListFor helper mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this part of code that runs very well:

```
merge1.Statuses = db.JobStatus.Select(s => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = s.JobStatusID.ToString(),
            Text = s.JobStatusName
        }).ToList();
```

Now, I want to add a default value that is a dynamic value, depending on the database. So, I tried something like:

```
    private SelectListItem statuses(string defaultStatus)
    {
        db.JobStatus.Select(s => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = s.JobStatusID.ToString(),
            Text = s.JobStatusName, 
            defaultStatus

        }).ToList();
        return ???
    }
```

So, I have marked red on defaultStatus.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If your binding to a property, then its the value of the property that determines the option that is selected. Set the value of your property to its default before you pass it to the view. Note that setting the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is pointless when using `DropDownListFor()` - its ignored.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> statuses(string defaultStatus)
{
   return db.JobStatus.Select(s => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = s.JobStatusID.ToString(),
        Text = s.JobStatusName, 
        Selected = s.JobStatusName == defaultStatus

    }).ToList();
}
```

Also change the return type so you can bind it to a select list in the view.